# Incorrect Mod result in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting incorrect **Mod** operator result in VB.NET. I verified result with calculator, It gives correct result.

E.g In VB.NET `1.3 Mod 0.05 = 0.049999999999999975` whereas in Calculator it shows `0`

Comment: What is the datatype of 1.3 and 0.05?

Comment: **Double**. I checked it with quick watch too.

Comment: It's round up error: `1.30000000000001 Mod 0.05 == 0.00000000000001`; `1.2999999 Mod 0.05 == 0.0499998999999999`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes... So, Do I need to round the result?.

Comment: Change the datatype to decimals

Comment: @gefrag No, I can't change my DataType..

Comment: The result is correct, 1.30 does not have an exact representation when it is converted to Double.  A numerical type that stores values in binary (base 2), 1.30 is not a finite sum of powers of 2.  So the endless number of 1s and 0s needs to be truncated, Double is not an arbitrary precision type like the type your calculator uses.  That makes the value a wee bit less than 1.30.   If you want happy numbers that match your calculator then you must use Decimal so the conversion to base 2 is not necessary.  1.3D Mod 0.05D gives you what you want.  This is why the Decimal type exists.  Basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *round up* error:

```
1.30000000000001 Mod 0.05 == 0.00000000000001 
1.2999999        Mod 0.05 == 0.0499998999999999
```

usually, round up errors are little (if any) nuisance, put at / near *points of discontinuity* small errors lead to big difference at the result (`0.05` in this case).

Amendment: change the initial `double` to either `int` (`long`)

```
130 Mod 5 == 0
```

or `decimal`:

```
1.3M Mod 0.05M == 0
```

Comment: No. It´s how double was implemented and meant to be.

Comment: @Amol Bavannavar: it's; `double` as well as `float` is prone to round up errors, and at/near the *points of discontinuity* you'll have weird outcomes

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ohhh I see... I solved it with multiplying 100 and dividing by 5 instead of 0.05... Thanks Dmitry...